# Laravel - routing a child controller on child route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have the following route:

```
Route::controller('/boards', 'BoardController');
```

which responds to the following routes:

```
/boards -> function: getIndex()
/boards/board/Some-board-Alias -> function: getBoard()
```

what I want to do is - when I enter the following route:

```
/boards/board/Some-board-Alias/items
```

it will execute "BoardItemController", function: getItem()

I tried doing something like this:

```
Route::controller('/boards/board/{board_alias}/items', 'BoardItemController');
```

But when I enter the following route:

```
/boards/board/Some-board-Alias/items
```

it displays the content from:

```
/boards/board/Some-board-Alias
```

Looks like it treats "items" as a param and not as part of the route.
is there a way using another controller for sub route?

---

Just to make it clear The route:

```
/boards/board/Some-board-Alias
```

Should access BoardController@getBoard (using Route::controller)

```
/boards/board/some-board-Alias/items
```

Should access BoardItemController@getIndex (using Route::controller)
also:

```
/boards/board/some-board-alias/items/item/123
```

Should access BoardItemController@getItem($id) (using Route::controller)

Comment: it will be very easy if you map the calls. without it, the codes will always be very dirty and unreliable. (if you change something in future, it can be a headache).

Comment: What do you mean map the calls?

Answer (score 1):

You can have your routes defined like this. Order is important, since Laravel will take the first route matching the URL pattern.

```
// If it's this specific route, go to `BoardItemController->getItem()`
Route::get('boards/board/{board_alias}/items', 'BoardItemController@getItem');
// If not, try to find another one in the rest of the file
Route::controller('boards', 'BoardController');
```

Then, in your controller:

```
// BoardItemController.php
public function getItem($alias)
{
    // do awesome stuff
}
```

As a side note, don't use the leading slash when defining your routes:

```
Route::controller('boards'); // right
Route::controller('/boards'); // wrong
```

Comment: Thanks for the side note, took that in mind.

What you mentioned about the size routes applies to resource route. if you will do lets say /board/bonzo it will execute getBonzo() function in BoardController - this is the behavior I want.

Comment: @VladKucherov fixed now :)

Comment: Well that's a working idea but like in BoardController, BoardItemController also should work as controller. I don't want to map all the avaliable functions inside BoardItemController. boards/board/{board_alias}/items should execute getIndex() and boards/board/{board_alias}/items/item/123 should execute getItem($id) and so on...

Comment: Well, I'm afraid you should rethink your URLs then.

Comment: That`s sad, are you sure this is impossible?

Comment: I can't figure out how the framework is going to differentiate between when to use `BoardController` and `BoardItemController` with those requirements. But no, I'm not sure it's impossible... Maybe someone has a better answer.

Comment: Well I figured a working solution but its pretty nasty:

Route::controller('/boards/board/{board_alias}/items', 'BoardItemController');
Route::controller('/boards', 'BoardController');